# detached entity passed to persist: mn.bolig.bmdomain.companyowner.CompanyOwner

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Im using Spring boot 2.6.13, and calling a streamed repository method, in a scheduled function (running every minute).

```
@Transactional
@Scheduled(cron = "0/60 * * ? * *") // every minute
fun scheduledCall() {
  
    ownerRepo.streamAllByArchivedIsFalseAndDeletedIsFalse().forEach { owner ->
        anotherRepo.findByOwner(owner)
        em.detach(owner)
    }
}
```

On the second iteration of the forEach, the call anotherRepo.findByOwner(owner) throws :

> detached entity passed to persist: x.y.z.Owner

All models returned in the stream are distinct x.y.z.Owner instances.

What could the issue be?

Tried updating Spring boot, Spring Data and such. But same result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the whole project, so this is just an assumption. The most common problem when using `@Transactional` annotation is misunderstanding of its nature. [Here is a brief description](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring#1-transactions-and-proxies). In short, at the moment `@Transactional` is ignored, and you should probably separate scheduling and business operation. For instance, create one more bean with `public` method that will fetch and process data. Or move out the scheduling to someone of configuration classes.

Another way is to get rid of `@Transactional` and use `TransactionTemplate` or whatever to do the stuff within a transaction, which you'll control explicitly.

And, of course, don't forget to enable transaction management by adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` to the config or application class. Honestly, it's not always necessary due to its enabling by default, but it depends on a bunch of cases (`Spring` version, another configuration annotations etc., I don't know, how did you configure a project) and it will break nothing if added.